# How do I find if a branch has been merged to any branch (not just a specific one)

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-branch, git-merge

I'm trying to clean up some branches in a fairly large project. We essentially have master, a bunch of release branches (of which only the most recent is maintained), and feature/bug fix branches off each release.

The process is normally bugfix/feature-branch -> current-release-branch -> master

Now I can see there's quite a few old feature/bugfix branches that are ahead of master - but what I want to do is find if they were at least merged to a release branch.

Then I can at least clean up all feature/bugfix branches which have been merged to release branches, leaving me to only manually work out a) what's missing in master that's on release-branches, and b) any feature branches that were never merged at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git branch -a --merged {commit}` to list all branches that are reachable from specified commit
`--no-merged` to list all non reachable branches

That's what you need.

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch

"With --contains, shows only the branches that contain the named commit (in other words, the branches whose tip commits are descendants of the named commit). With --merged, only branches merged into the named commit (i.e. the branches whose tip commits are reachable from the named commit) will be listed. With --no-merged only branches not merged into the named commit will be listed. If the  argument is missing it defaults to HEAD (i.e. the tip of the current branch)."

Comment: Thanks - so to clarify, I need to run this command for every release branch, and that will give me all features/bug fix branches that aren't at least merged to a feature branch?

Comment: I'd say to start filtering out from the branches that are not merged into master. Then you have an option of either using --contains {feature_branch} or --merged {release_branch} depending on what is easier to process for you.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as

```
git branch -a --contains <id>
```

Where `<id>` might be a changeset iв, a tag name or a branch name